# How to change the scale of a point in an animated plot in R gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am making an animated plot showing three variables over time, in two categories of data point.  I need the point in the visualisation to be scaled according to one of the variables, in this case v3.  In the MRE below this works fine, but I'd like my points to be much bigger, say 2 - 3 times bigger, but still scaled to v3.  If I set the geom_point size then it will fix the points at the size I specify, but they will change according to v3.  I've also tried mutiplying v3 by something in the ggplot code itself which has no effect.  Can someone suggest how to do this.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

#make some data
set.seed(22)
t<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
cat<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b")
v1<-sample(x = 1:10, size  = 20, replace=TRUE)
v2<-sample(x = 1:10, size  = 20, replace=TRUE)
v3<-sample(x=1:5, size = 20, replace=TRUE)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(t,cat,v1,v2,v3))

df$t<-as.integer(df$t)
df$cat<-as.factor(df$cat)
df$v1<-as.integer(df$v1)
df$v2<-as.integer(df$v2)
df$v3<-as.integer(df$v3)

#build my plot showing size of v3 for categories 'a' and 'b' over time t
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(v1, v2, size = v3, color = cat, frame = t)) +
labs(x="Variable 1", y = "Variable 2")+ 
ylim(0,10) +
geom_point() +
scale_color_brewer(type = 'div', palette = 'Spectral') + 
# gganimate code
ggtitle("period: {frame_time}") +
transition_time(t) +
ease_aes("linear") +
enter_fade() +
exit_fade()
# animate
animate(p1, width =650, height = 450)
```

Comment: Small error in text. should read "if i set the geom_point size it will fix the points at the size I specify but they will NOT change according to v3"

Comment: You could set range used for `size` via `scale_size(range = ..)`, where `range = c(1, 6)` is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this.  Thanks to Stefan for suggesting scale_size_range.  I could use this to make the points bigger but they did not scale.  However by using scale_size_area and setting the max_size I can achieve what I need.  So in this very extreme example, using the original MRE data set...

```
#build my plot showing size of v3 for categories 'a' and 'b' over time t
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(v1, v2, size = v3, color = cat, frame = t)) +
labs(x="Variable 1", y = "Variable 2")+ 
ylim(0,10) +
geom_point() +
scale_color_brewer(type = 'div', palette = 'Spectral') + 
scale_size_area(max_size=40)+
# gganimate code
ggtitle("period: {frame_time}") +
transition_time(t) +
ease_aes("linear") +
enter_fade() +
exit_fade()
# animate
animate(p1, width =650, height = 450)
```

OK, this produces an odd looking plot, but it demonstrates the principle.